# Keytool says alias both exists and does not exist. How do I start from scratch with a clean slate?

Tags: java, keytool

For a project I'm working on, we need certificates in order to authenticate. When I first ran keytool.exe, I got the following:

```
> keytool.exe -list
Your keystore contains 0 entries
```

However, I attempted to import the certificates incorrectly like this:

```
keytool.exe -import -alias dev01 -file cacert1.crt -keystore C:\Dev\Resources\Java\JDK_7\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

Then when I ran a listing I got this:

```
> keytool.exe -list
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 0 entries
```

So, I thought "Strange, I'll do it again." So I ran the command again, but keytool gave me this error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias <dev01> already exists
```

Then when I ran a listing I got this:

```
> keytool.exe -list
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 0 entries
```

However, whenever I do a listing, keytool always says I have 0 entries. Then, I discovered from a co-worker that the command I really needed to run is:

```
keytool.exe -import -trustcacerts -file cacert1.crt -alias dev01 -keystore C:\Dev\Resources\Java\JDK_7\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

I tried to delete the "JKS" and "SUN", but I cannot figure out how. At this point, all I want to is go back to a clean slate, and start all over with the correct import command. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

When you import, you are specifying a keystore, but when you are issuing the -list command you are not specifying that same keystore, try this:

```
keytool.exe -list -keystore C:\Dev\Resources\Java\JDK_7\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```